# Number of paths to a specific vertex in the Young's lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, young-tableaux

Consider the [Young's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_lattice). *What is the number of paths starting from the origin (0) to a specific Young diagram?*

For instance, the Young diagram corresponding to the integer partition 1+1+1 has 1 path leading to it, 2+1 has 2 paths leading to it and 2+2 has 2 paths leading to it.

Is there a generating function to get this combinatorics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These paths are the same thing as standard Young tableaux, which are enumerated by the famous [Hook Length Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula).

Comment: Thanks! Are the some well known polynomials that capture these hook lengths? Something along the lines of: $x_1^2 +x_2$ for N=2, $x_1^3+2x_1x_2+x_3$ for N=3.. and so on? If yes, is there a generating function for this?

Comment: @TheTwistedSector: are you asking for a formula for the number of SYTs of shape $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$ in terms of the $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$? There is such a formula due to Frobenius/Young, which significantly predates the Hook Length Formula, using a determinant. See Theorem 2.1.2 of https://users.math.msu.edu/users/bsagan/papers/old/uyt.pdf.

Comment: Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_\ell)$ be a partition of $n$. If instead of $x_{\lambda_1}\cdots x_{\lambda_\ell}$ you use the Schur function $s_\lambda$ (in the variables $y_1,y_2,\dots$), and if $f^\lambda$ denotes the number of paths from $(0)$ to $\lambda$, then $\sum_\lambda f^\lambda s_\lambda= s_1^n = (y_1+y_2+\cdots)^n$, where $\lambda$ ranges over all partitions of $n$. One place where this theory is developed is Chapter 7 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @SamHopkins Yes, I was asking for that formula in terms of the $\lambda_i$'s. 

However, why is it that the number of SYTs = the number of paths? Is there some intuitive way to understand it?

Comment: I guess it is because the fillings of the SYTs indicate the order in which the boxes can be added to arrive at a specific diagram. Is this correct?

Comment: @TheTwistedSector: yes, the numbers in the boxes tell you the order they are added when going from $\varnothing$ to $\lambda$ one box at a time. This is implicit in Christian's answer.